# Is possible create extra sp sp_user_counter

Tags: sql-server

Can mssql has more than ten sp_user_counter?

For example from sp_user_counter11 to sp_user_counter20.

Am I able to create these procedures?

Comment: `sp_user_count` what does this procedure do? 2. As long as sp has different name and does not collide with existing one you could create multiple of them

Comment: You are, You can create multiple of them if one by one of them is a unique name
you absolutely create these procedures

Comment: There's no such Special Procedure called `sp_user_count`.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the [`sp_user_counter{n}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-user-settable-object?view=sql-server-ver15) Special Procedures?

Comment: Yes, I mean sp_user_counter{n}. It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can mssql has more than ten sp_user_counter?

No.  SQL Server has 10 user-defined performance counters, and you can't create or set more of them.

You could use a CLR stored procedures to write to your own performance counters.

Or utilize [user-defined trace events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-generateevent-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which you can monitor with [SQL Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/view-the-extended-events-equivalents-to-sql-trace-event-classes?view=sql-server-ver15).